# Как сделать, чтобы в выпадающем списке фильтра были только термины, у которых есть ноды?

Tags: drupal, php, views

Дано:

1. Views.
2. Exposed filter (термины таксономии).

Как сделать, чтобы в выпадающем списке фильтра были только термины, у которых есть ноды? Иначе говоря: как из списка исключить термины, к которым не привязано ни одной ноды?

**Обновление**

1. Это делает Views Selective Exposed Filters.
2. Выбрать фильтр с пометкой selective.
3. Если надо фильтровать по полю, которое отсутствует в выводе, включить его, и  после этого скрыть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать элементарно с помощью `hook_form_alter` http://drup.by/snippets/ogranichenie-dopustimogo-vybora-v-exposed-filters